# What are the "unspecified" credentials in the YouTube Data API v3 Metrics dashboard?

Tags: api, youtube-data-api, credentials, metrics

I'm tracing the calls to the YouTube Data API v3 from my application in order to check on quota overflows and when I look at the "Metrics" dashboards under "credentials" I see `other = unspecified` with lots of calls. But all my calls use API KEYs.

Does anyone know what this `other = unspecified` is?

[image: Youtube DATA API Metrics dashboard]

Comment: Did you ever get an answer elsewhere?

Comment: No comments at all.